# Piping data to a Python Program on Raspberry Pi / Rasbian OS

Tags: pipe, raspberry-pi

Folks, I'm spying on traffic coming from one of my Internet devices.  I have set up the Raspberry Pi as a bridge.  When I run this script (saved and set as executable "spy")

```
sudo tcpdump -A -n -p -l -i eth0 -s0 -w - tcp dst port 80 | stdbuf -oL strings -n10
```

I see the records of interest displayed on the terminal screen:

```
id=11824&mt=a&length=A0580&density=A018600000&battery=normal&watts=4
id=04382&mt=b&length=A0970&density=A005111112&battery=normal&watts=4"
id=02606&mt=c&length=A0770&density=A005800000&battery=normal&watts=4'
id=02174&mt=d8&length=A0990&density=A005222224&battery=normal&watts=4+
id=11824&mt=a&length=A0580&density=A018600000&battery=normal&watts=4/
```

I have created this simple Python program to display the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
# test data
#f = open('/mnt/usbdrive/output/data.txt', 'r')
i=0
try:
#  for line in f:
  for line in sys.stdin:
    i=i+1
    print "\ninput line is \n--", line, "--\n"
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print('Done', i)
# f.close()
```

If I cut and past these records into a file and open that file for reading (commented lines) it works correctly.  However if I try to pipe the script output to my Python program, it just sets there.

```
spy | python /mnt/usbdrive/pgms/TestPipe.py
```

When I break out the script after several minutes, it says that it has processed many records/packets but the Python output say no lines were read, ie I is output as zero.

Raspberry Pi is running Raspian OS (Debian wheezy, I assume).

What am I doing wrong?.....RDK

Answer (score 0):

Folks....I found the answer, replace

```
 for line in sys.stdin:
```

with

```
while 1:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Now working perfectly.  not sure why my original code did not work, but....RDK